# Indexerror:::: list index out of range

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, index-error

hi this is my code and I don't know why I received this type of error

```
x = int(input())
n = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

middle = n[int((x - 1) / 2)

even = 0
odd = 0
for number in n:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even += number
    else:
        odd += number

answer = even * odd + middle ** 2

print("{} x {} + {}^2 = {}".format(even, odd, middle, answer))
```

Comment: Can you share the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: `x-1/2` is less than the length of n

Answer (score 1):

It produces an error as such `IndexError: list index out of range` because n has the minimum number of list values entered by the user.

Since your intention was for n to have more values than the minimum number of digits entered by the user, I added `.range()` to the list iteration.

Here is the modified code:

```
x = int(input("Put in a number: "))
n = [int(i) for i in range(int(input("Put in another number: ")))]

middle = n[int((x - 1) / 2)]

even = 0
odd = 0
for number in n:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even += number
    else:
        odd += number

answer = even * odd + middle ** 2

print("{} x {} + {}^2 = {}".format(even, odd, middle, answer))
```

If you have any questions or need clarification, please do not hesitate to ask.